# Не получается найти разделитель

Tags: python, pandas

Есть файл txt, мне нужно читать его как датафрейм по колонкам, но никак не получается разделить на столбцы...
Ссылка на файл https://disk.yandex.ru/d/-e-XklG_SBXxHg

Помогите, пожалуйста..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('CH1980BST.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
              0  1    2     3     4   5    6           7           8
0         66666  0   41     1     0   0  6.0  (nameless)  20110729.0
1    1980031718  1   85  1420  1008  12  NaN         NaN         NaN
2    1980031800  1   85  1410  1006  15  NaN         NaN         NaN
3    1980031806  1   85  1400  1005  15  NaN         NaN         NaN
4    1980031812  1   86  1393  1005  15  NaN         NaN         NaN
..          ... ..  ...   ...   ...  ..  ...         ...         ...
982  1980122112  1  118  1269  1004  12  NaN         NaN         NaN
983  1980122118  1  112  1268  1004  12  NaN         NaN         NaN
984  1980122200  1  105  1267  1004  12  NaN         NaN         NaN
985  1980122206  0  100  1265  1004  10  NaN         NaN         NaN
986  1980122212  0   95  1260  1006  10  NaN         NaN         NaN

[987 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]